# How to do an invert selection in emacs?

Tags: emacs, textselection

I currently have a region of text selected. I want to kill/yank (or format in any other way) the whole buffer except the selected region. Is there any way in which I can do an invert selection in emacs and accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <kbd>C-w</kbd> `kill-region` the text in the middle.
2. <kbd>C-x h</kbd> `mark-whole-buffer` the rest of the text.
3. do your thing.
4. <kbd>C-y</kbd> `yank` the middle text.

Comment: But once the rest of the text is killed for example, then wouldn't the `kill ring` be affected? Then step 4 might not yield the desired result.

Comment: Then just use `M-y`. It's a ring it can fit much more than one kill.

Answer (score 1):

```el
(defun my-copy-inverted-region-as-kill (beginning end)
  "Copy to the kill ring everything except the marked region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((srcbuf (current-buffer))
        (offset (point-min)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-buffer-substring srcbuf)
      (delete-region (- beginning offset) (- end offset))
      (copy-region-as-kill (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-contiguous regions can't exist.
However, this puts the opposite command on C-c DEL

```
(global-set-key "\^C\^?"        ; help edit mail files, etc.
        (defun erase-buffer-except-region (beg end)
          "Erase the buffer except for the region."
          (interactive "r")
          (when (< end beg)
            (cl-rotatef beg end))
          (delete-region end (point-max))
          (delete-region (point-min) beg)))
```

Comment: Perhaps the highlight library should let you either delete or keep highlighted areas, which can be non-contiguous.